# How to get max value of corresponding item in many arrays in DataFrame column?

Tags: scala, dataframe

A DataFrame as following:

```
import spark.implicits._
val df1 = List(
    ("id1", Array(0,2)),
    ("id1",Array(2,1)),
    ("id2",Array(0,3))
  ).toDF("id", "value")

+---+------+
| id| value|
+---+------+
|id1|[0, 2]|
|id1|[2, 1]|
|id2|[0, 3]|
+---+------+
```

I want to groupBy id to get max pooling of every value array. Max id1 value is Array(2,2). The result I want to get is:

```
import spark.implicits._
val res = List(
    ("id1", Array(2,2)),
    ("id2",Array(0,3))
  ).toDF("id", "value")

+---+------+
| id| value|
+---+------+
|id1|[2, 2]|
|id2|[0, 3]|
+---+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import spark.implicits._
val df1 = List(
  ("id1", Array(0,2,3)),
  ("id1",Array(2,1,4)),
  ("id2",Array(0,7,3))
).toDF("id", "value")
val df2rdd = df1.rdd
  .map(x => (x(0).toString,x.getSeq[Int](1)))
  .reduceByKey((x,y) => {
    val arrlength = x.length
    var i = 0
    val resarr = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]()
    while(i < arrlength){
      if (x(i) >= y(i)){
        resarr.append(x(i))
      } else {
        resarr.append(y(i))
      }
      i += 1
    }
    resarr
  }).toDF("id","newvalue")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below

```
//Input df
+---+---------+
| id|    value|
+---+---------+
|id1|[0, 2, 3]|
|id1|[2, 1, 4]|
|id2|[0, 7, 3]|
+---+---------+

//Solution approach: 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val df1=df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_set("value").as("value"))
val maxUDF = udf{(s:Seq[Seq[Int]])=>s.reduceLeft((prev,next)=>prev.zip(next).map(tup=>if(tup._1>tup._2) tup._1 else tup._2))}
df1.withColumn("value",maxUDF(df1.col("value"))).show

//Sample Output:
+---+---------+
| id|    value|
+---+---------+
|id1|[2, 2, 4]|
|id2|[0, 7, 3]|
+---+---------+
```

I hope, this will help you.

Comment: Not this mean. I want to get max（0，2）and （2，1）of id1, not the max two elements of all.

Comment: Not this mean. I want to get max（0，5）and （4，1）of id1, not the max two elements of all like yours `val getMaxTwoUDF=udf{(x:WrappedArray[WrappedArray[Int]])=> x.flatten.sorted.takeRight(2)}`. And not max of each array like mine `s.map(_.max)`

Comment: Hi @garyyong, I modified my solution for your desired output.

Comment: If want to get mean number.The UDF will be `val meanUDF = udf{(s:Seq[Seq[Int]])=>s.reduceLeft((prev,next)=>prev.zip(next).map(tup=>tup._1+tup._2)).map(_/s.length)}`